# Limit of this expression when n tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

The limit is equal to: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} dx$$

P.S. What should be the better approach for such kinds of problems?

Comment: Just substitute x = tan k and your integral will become cos^(2n-2)k dk, Now, use reduction formula to see that the first term itself is infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bit overkill but at least it works to show the divergence of the sequence and gives a nice additional result:

- Consider first $I_n = \int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$.
- To bring in somehow the exponential function susbtitute $nx^2 = y$:
  $$I_n =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\underbrace{\int_0^n\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}\left(1+\frac{y}{n}\right)^{n}}}_{J_n := }$$
- Now, using DCT (dominated convergence theorem) gives
  $$J_n \stackrel{DCT:\;n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt{y}}dy = \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Hence, we see 
$$n^2I_n = n^2\frac{J_n}{2\sqrt{n}}= \frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2}\underbrace{J_n}_{\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\sqrt{\pi}} \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$$

p.s.:

The additional nice result is that 
$$\sqrt{n}I_n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $n\geq 2$,
$$a_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^n} = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2n-2}\,d\theta\leq \int_{0}^{\pi/4}e^{-(n-1)\theta^2}\,d\theta\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(n-1)\theta^2}\,d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{n-1}} $$
since $\cos(x)\leq e^{-x^2/2}$ can be deduced by integrating $\tan(x)>x$. On the other hand the convexity of $\tan(x)$ implies that over $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$ we have $\log\cos(x)\leq -\frac{x^2}{3}$, so
$$ a_n \geq \int_{0}^{\pi/4}e^{-\frac{3}{2}(n-1)\theta^2}\,d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{6(n-1)}}-\int_{\pi/4}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{3}{2}(n-1)\theta^2}\,d\theta $$
where
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{3}{2}(n-1)\theta^2}\,d\theta\leq \int_{\pi/4}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{3\pi}{8}(n-1)\theta}\,d\theta=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
This gives that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}n^{\alpha}a_n$ equals $+\infty$ for any $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
When $\ds{n \to \infty}$, the main contribution to the integral comes from a right neighborhood of $\ds{x = 0}$. Namely, with
[Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method)
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{2}\int_{0}^{1}
{\dd x \over \pars{1 +x^{2}}^{n}}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{2}\int_{0}^{1}
\expo{-n\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{n^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nx^{2}}\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{n^{2}\,{\root{\pi} \over 2n^{1/2}}} =\
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px solid navy]{+\infty}
\end{align}